# ASP.NET Decimal.Parse()

Tags: asp.net

I have problem in webpage , Visual Studio claims that problem is with this line `decimal newAmount = PLNamount * Decimal.Parse(item.Value);`. The solution is crushed when I choose the Current (web page is simple current converter) .

this is listing of **CurrencyConverter.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
public partial class CurrencyConverter : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // The HtmlSelect control accepts text or ListItem objects.
            Currency.Items.Add(new ListItem("Euros", "0.25"));
            Currency.Items.Add(new ListItem("US Dollar", "0.32"));
            Currency.Items.Add(new ListItem("British Pound", "0.205"));
        }
    }
    protected void Convert_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        decimal PLNamount;
        
        bool success = Decimal.TryParse(PLN.Value,out PLNamount);
        if (success)
        {
            PLNamount = Decimal.Parse(PLN.Value);
            ListItem item = Currency.Items[Currency.SelectedIndex];
            decimal newAmount = PLNamount * Decimal.Parse(item.Value); //prollematic line

            Result.InnerText = PLNamount.ToString() + " Polish PLN = ";
            Result.InnerText += newAmount.ToString() + " " + item.Text;
        }
        else Result.InnerText = "Invalid content";
    }
}
```

This is listing of **CurrencyConverter.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="CurrencyConverter.aspx.cs" Inherits="CurrencyConverter" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Currency Converter</title>
</head>
<body>
Simple Currency Converter in ASP.NET web forms <br />

<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<div>
Convert: &nbsp;
<input type="text" ID="PLN" runat="server" />
&nbsp; Polish PLN to Euros.
<select ID="Currency" runat="server" />
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="OK" ID="Convert" runat="server"
OnServerClick="Convert_ServerClick" />
<br /><br />
<div style="font-weight: bold" ID="Result" runat="server"></div>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This Code is changed listing from apress "Pro ASP.NET 3.5 in C# 2008, Second Edition" (original version) from chapter 5. Link to source code apress.com/book/downloadfile/3803 . I have exactly the same problem in the same line

Original source code from the book

**aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="CurrencyConverter.aspx.cs" Inherits="CurrencyConverter" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Currency Converter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form ID="Form1" method="post" runat="server">

        <div style="border-right: thin ridge; padding-right: 20px; border-top: thin ridge;
            padding-left: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; border-left: thin ridge; width: 531px;
            padding-top: 20px; border-bottom: thin ridge; font-family: Verdana; background-color: #FFFFE8">
        Convert: &nbsp;
        <input type="text" ID="US" runat="server" style="width: 102px" />&nbsp; U.S. dollars to &nbsp;
        <select ID="Currency" runat="server" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="OK" ID="Convert" runat="server" OnServerClick="Convert_ServerClick" />
        <input type="submit" value="Show Graph" ID="ShowGraph" runat="server" OnServerClick="ShowGraph_ServerClick" />
        <br /><br />
        <img ID="Graph" alt="Currency Graph" scr="" runat="server" />
        <br /><br />
        <div style="font-weight: bold" ID="Result" runat="server"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class CurrencyConverter : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            // The HtmlSelect control accepts text or ListItem objects.
            Currency.Items.Add(new ListItem("Euros", "0.85"));
            Currency.Items.Add(new ListItem("Japanese Yen", "110.33"));
            Currency.Items.Add(new ListItem("Canadian Dollars", "1.2"));
        }
        Graph.Visible = false;
    }
    protected void Convert_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal amount;
        bool success = Decimal.TryParse(US.Value, out amount);
        if (success)
        {
            // Retrieve the selected ListItem object by its index number.
            ListItem item = Currency.Items[Currency.SelectedIndex];

            decimal newAmount = amount * Decimal.Parse(item.Value);
            Result.InnerText = amount.ToString() + " U.S. dollars = ";
            Result.InnerText += newAmount.ToString() + " " + item.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            Result.InnerText = "The number you typed in was not in the correct format. ";
            Result.InnerText += "Use only numbers.";
        }
    }

    protected void ShowGraph_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graph.Src = "Pic" + Currency.SelectedIndex.ToString() + ".png";
        Graph.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

**Problem solved**

This is link to print screen with this error. http://img210.imageshack.us/f/currencyerror.png/

Comment: Why are you doing the parsing twice? When you do tryParse you get the result, if success==true, but then you repeat it.

Comment: I just copy and pasted the code from the question and it works fine for me... What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I've chenged that , not it looks like this:  decimal PLNamount;
        
        bool success = Decimal.TryParse(PLN.Value,out PLNamount);

Comment: I have't got any error while compiling , the error shows when you insert amount into input and click OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is localisation based. I suspect you are parsing "0.25" as a decimal in your a culture style which uses commas as decimal separators. What you need to do is to specify what style the numbers are in so that it interprets them correctly. One way to do this is:

```
decimal newAmount = PLNamount * Decimal.Parse(item.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat)
```

Hopefully people will comment if there is a nicer way of doing it.

Hope that helps. I've not confirmed that this is definitely your problem but if I try to parse the number as pl-PL (just guessing you are polish from the page) then it fails for me on that line you quoted so I reckon I'm on the right lines. :)

**Edit to add:** The other option is to change your dropdown to have values like "0,25" which should parse correctly. However, I personally would prefer to use the CultureInfo option.

Interestingly when I enter numbers into the box on the page it seems to recognise "0.9" and "0,9" as the same thing. Not sure why it works there but I guess its related to tryParse and Parse workign subtly differently.

Comment: yes I am polish , but it is't about culture it is about html control.
I cant write  Currency.Items.Add(new ListItem("Euros", 0.25)); //without inverted commas. I have to write  Currency.Items.Add(new ListItem("Euros", "0.25"));

Comment: This Code is changed listing from apress "Pro ASP.NET 3.5 in C# 2008, Second Edition" (original version) from chapter 5. Link to source code
http://apress.com/book/downloadfile/3803 . I have exactly the same problem in the same line.

Comment: @Konrad: You can't write it without the quotes because listitems dont' contain numbers, they contain strings because that is how HTML works. That's why you have to parse them. Did you try putting the invariantculture in to see if that would work becasue I'm 90% confident it will based on my own tests. Its all about the fact that your computer is polish and expects numbers in a different format to the one in which we are giving it.

Comment: I have Windows 7 professional ENG , I have only polish localization.

Comment: I give numbers more tha 0 and I dont use any dots or commas in input.
I always given 300 or so.

Comment: Its not the numbers you are inputting in your textbox. Its the numbers you are putting in your dropdown list in your page_load method. And the .NET install should have all the necessary stuff available to do my suggested fix above. Yuu might have to add in a "using System.Globalization" at the top too to let you access teh CultureInfo object.

Comment: YES it work's ! Thanks You very much for your advice.

But I dont' understand why I have such problem ? 
I was using dots (like in English culture) in page_load method .

Comment: The problem is that by default your computer is parsing them according to CultureInfo.CurrentInfo which is set to pl-PL (probably). When you are compiling the numbers in Page_load are just strings so it doesn't care what it looks like. Its only when you postback that you start using them as numbers at which point it tries to interpret them as your local style. There probably is a way to globally set your program to use a specific culture rather than specifyign it every time you parse but off the top of my head I can't tell you what. Just ask another question if you want to know. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do both:

```
    bool success = Decimal.TryParse(PLN.Value,out PLNamount);
    if (success)
    {
        PLNamount = Decimal.Parse(PLN.Value);
```

If the `TryParse` succeeded then `PLNamount` will contain the correct value. Check the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx) for `TryParse`.

Also:

```
        ListItem item = Currency.Items[Currency.SelectedIndex];
        decimal newAmount = PLNamount * Decimal.Parse(item.Value); //prollematic line
```

if the value in `item` isn't a string representing a number `Parse` will throw an exception. For safety you should use `TryParse` on this value as well (if it's not already a numeric type of course).

Comment: item.Value is String . //I've checked in debuger eg. item.Value has "0.25" in string format with inverted commas.

Comment: @Konrad - try breaking the line up so you convert the string to a number on one line and the multiplication on another. It might shed some light on what exactly is going on.

Comment: @Konrad - in your "answer" you state that "item.Value is string in 100%", not "0.25" as you stated here. If that's the case then the `Decimal.Parse` will fail because of the "%" sign. You need to strip this off before trying to convert the string to a number.

Comment: I assume that's a language issue and he's meaning that they are strings 100% of the time. As I've said in my answer I suspect its a localisation thing whereby the Decimal.Parse is expecting "0,25" instead of 0.25. you shouldn't really need tryParse when you are controlling the input values fully. Yeah, somebody could hack it to pass a different value but I'm not sure I see a problem in failing in that situation...

Answer (score 0):

you should delete the following line

```
 PLNamount = Decimal.Parse(PLN.Value);
```

if(success) ... then PLNamount are already parsed, it is an out parameter...

Comment: That's not the solution. The exception was on another code line

Answer (score 0):

Parse throws an exception if the value being parsed isn't a decimal.  TryParse is safer in that respect; it returns a bool if it is a decimal, and returns the value through an output parameter, but you should check that TryParse returns true.

```
if (decimal.TryParse("12", out decValue)) { .. }
```

Using TryParse for the item check, where the error occurs, too may help...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is't solved .
item.Value is string in 100% //debuger confirms that.

I don't know what I have to do.

Comment: You should add this extra information to your question, rather than posting it as an answer (which it isn't)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is this, assuming it's a value from a DropDown that always contains percentages.

```
decimal ItemValue = Decimal.Parse(Item.Value.Substring(0, Item.Value.IndexOf('%')));
```

It strips the % from the string and then converts the remainder to a decimal.

Comment: I don't understand what You mean.

Comment: He has given the code above. You can see that the dropdown doesn't contain percentages.

Comment: He said it does contain percentage, though the select doesn't contain anytything, maybe he stripped it to suit it for display here.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your debug, item.value = "US Dollar".  This is a string value, you've probably want the "Text" property.

Comment: No , it is correct debuger shows me item.Value contains "0.25" (in case od US Dollars)

Comment: Like others, I just did a c/p of your source code added "using System;" and it worked perfectly.  I used VS2008 Developer Edition and added the code to a new "ASP.NET Web Site" project.  I built the source against 3.5 & 2.0 versions of the .NET framework.